# How can I get the actual text from a beautiful soup class tag?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

- Python Version: 3.8
- bs4 library

I have the following HTML which represents 2 of about 20+ reviews I have scraped. I didn't include the rest here because of space, but you can imagine that these blocks keep repeating.

I need to retrieve "sml-rank-stars sml-str40 star" (as seen in the second line here) from each review.

```html
<div class="review-rank">
<span class="sml-rank-stars sml-str40 star"></span>
<span class="score">
<span class="item">
                                                        口味：3.5
                                                    </span>
<span class="item">
                                                        环境：4.0
                                                    </span>
<span class="item">
                                                        服务：3.5
                                                    </span>
<span class="item">人均：200元</span>
</span>
</div>
<div class="review-rank">
<span class="sml-rank-stars sml-str35 star"></span>
<span class="score">
<span class="item">
                                                        口味：3.0
                                                    </span>
<span class="item">
                                                        环境：4.5
                                                    </span>
<span class="item">
                                                        服务：3.0
                                                    </span>
</span>
</div>
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
for review in review_items.find_all('div', class_='main-review'):
    review_rank = review.find('div', class_='review-rank')

    star_rank = []
    for review in review_rank.find_all('span')[:1]:
        star_rank.append(review.get('class'))

print(star_rank)
```

I get the resulting output:

```
[['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str5', 'star']]
```

I can then use this code to get the number only:

```
star_rank[0][1][7:]
```

Output:

```
'5'
```

The problem with this is I am only getting one of the reviews, I need this line for every review stored in my list.

My desired output something like this or something that I can iterate over to get the number of stars for each review:

```
[['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str40', 'star'],
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str35', 'star'],
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str50', 'star'],
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str40', 'star'],
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str40', 'star'],
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str50', 'star'],
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str50', 'star'],
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str45', 'star'],
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str10', 'star'],
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str35', 'star'],
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str45', 'star'],
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str40', 'star'],
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str45', 'star'],
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str10', 'star'],
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str5', 'star']]
```

I have figured out how to print out a result like this with the following code, but I need it saved into a list or something else I can iterate over.

```
for review in review_items.find_all('div', class_='main-review'):
    review_rank = review.find('div', class_='review-rank')

    for review in review_rank.find_all('span')[:1]:
        print(review.get('class'))
```

Output:

```
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str40', 'star']
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str35', 'star']
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str50', 'star']
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str40', 'star']
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str40', 'star']
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str50', 'star']
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str50', 'star']
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str45', 'star']
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str10', 'star']
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str35', 'star']
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str45', 'star']
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str40', 'star']
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str45', 'star']
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str10', 'star']
['sml-rank-stars', 'sml-str5', 'star']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over all `.review-rank` select all of them - To get the the rank only use a list comprehension:

```
star_rank = []
for r in soup.select('.review-rank'):
    star_rank.append([s.replace('sml-str','') for s in r.span['class'] if 'sml-str' in s][0])
```

or as in your example, do not know the genaral structure what is above `review_items` and if there is only one or many:

```
star_rank = []
for review in review_items.find_all('div', class_='main-review'):
    for review in review.find_all('div', class_='review-rank'):
        star_rank.append([s.replace('sml-str','') for s in review.span['class'] if 'sml-str' in s][0])
```

#### Output

```
['40', '35']
```

Comment: I used the first solution using the list comprehension. Worked perfectly. Thank you!